# Best way to show transition between states

Tags: interface-design

I need to graphically represent transition between different states. The states list is dynamic. At one time only one state can be active. We have a product which gives the user ability to define manufacturing cycle.

For example One user may define the cycle as Design->Engineering->Manufacturing->Sales. Other user may define as Product Design->Product Engineering->Process Engineering->Manufacturing->Sales and Service.

We need to graphically represent the cycle created by user and also present that in which stage is it currently. For example if it is in Product engineering then we need to highlight it. Please suggest if any good examples are available for reference

For example presenting this cycle to user after he has created one (the one below is not accepted by the management), stating that its not a very good way to represent. They want some better way to represent the same. They are looking for attractive UI with nice colors. This rectangular shape was not taken well 
[image]

Comment: This appears to be idea gathering, brainstorming, and a request for free work to me.

Comment: All I am asking for is are there any examples available for same on internet that anybody may have come across

Comment: Thanks Dominos example is great, that is something I was looking for. If you put this as answer, I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are asking just graphics examples or a system to do that interactive.

If you just need some inspiration you can watch some videos about "motion graphics" https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=motion+graphics or "motion design" https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=motion+design

If the output format is a video the tool can be after effects, or a simmilar program, or an open source program like blender.

If you need interactivity probably the best bet is to use html5+Css3+JavaScript and probably a server side languaje, probably a database.

A JavaScript library that is well known is http://raphaeljs.com/ you can see demos of interactive graphics there.

Or Css3 animations if you does not need a lot of interactivity. https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=css+3+animations

Or a simple slide show. https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=fade%20slider